# Distinct count with condition to get unique date only

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need the Dax language to get the distinct count of my tenant records.
Below is the table, how can i get the distinct key like below? I only need to count in when the date is different and I have a long list of units.

| Unit Number | Defect Date | **Distinct Key** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Office | 1/1/2023 | 1 |
| Office | 1/1/2023 | 0 |
| Office | 1/1/2023 | 0 |
| Office | 2/2/2023 | 1 |
| Office | 3/3/2023 | 1 |

I tried a few of googled solution such as countif, distinct which did not give me the value I am looking for.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Are you trying to just count unique combinations of `Unit Number` and `Defect Date`? I'm getting XY-problem vibes from this question, as I don't immediately see the use of this `Distinct Key` column.

Comment: I need a single records of the defect date (no dupe in date), for example for office unit number, we are seeing 3 records for 1/1/2023 but i need a distinct key to take it as one only instead of 3 for 1/1/2023.

Answer (score 0):

To get the distinct count of units, considering only different dates, you need something like this:

```
CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Table'[Unit]), ALLEXCEPT('Table','Table'[Date]))
```

To get the table you have in PBI I don't think there is a way of doing it. With only those 2 columns, powerbi cannot tell the difference between any of the 3 records and they'd just be aggregated into a single record with a distinct count of 1

Comment: yea, tried your formula, it doesn't works as well. :(

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to get a distinct count of `Unit Number` and `Defect Date` you can use a measure that simply summarizes your data and counts rows:

```
Distinct Count = 
COUNTROWS (
    SUMMARIZE ( 
        'Table', 
        'Table'[Unit Number],
        'Table'[Defect Date]
    )
)
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not giving me the distinct count for date /unit number. :(

Comment: Do you expect a measure or a calculated column?